# Render a hidden element inside another hidden element using visible true

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net, visibility

**THE PROBLEM**

When a container is set to `visible="true"` its contents do not render if also set to `visible="true"` at the same time.

**EXAMPLE**

When `visible="true"` is set for a template field and a textbox within it (as below), the template field (entire column) is rendered but the textbox remains unrendered.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sample" Visible="false">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="Server" Visible="false"/>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The objective here is to render the entire column while only showing the textbox in select rows.

**WHY?**

I know this is occuring because the template field is not present at the time the textbox attempts to render.

I also know that if `display:none` *(maintaining the object in the DOM)* is used instead, rendering occurs as expected.

**QUESTION**

Assuming visible false must be used:

How can the textbox be set to visible true and rendered at the same time as the templatefield?

---

**NOTES:** For those who are going to ask why do you need visible false inside a hidden element? It is because every row *(templatefield)* will be rendered but only select textbox's.

Comment: The question is unclear.   How do you want to make a column invisible but a single `TextBox` inside visible? A `TemplateField` represents not the row but the whole column.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thank you I have made ammendments.

Comment: a container with display:none is invisible together with all its children, it has 0 height. You cannot force a child to be visible.

Comment: @florin.prisecariu display none is not used. The textbox will only ever be visible if the container is also visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For those who are going to ask why do you need visible false inside a hidden element? It is because every row (templatefield) will be rendered but only select textbox's.

You sort of answered your own question here, if every `TemplateField` needs to be rendered then setting `Visible=false` isn't the way to go. From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfield.visible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether a data control field is rendered.

Given you always want to render the `TemplateField` it's really the visibility of the `TextBox` you want to change, not the `TemplateField`. That can be accomplished many ways it all depends on exactly what sort of visibility you want e.g. if you want to render it but keep it hidden then you can set `visibility=hidden` in the CSS which means it would retain it's layout properties i.e. width/height etc. If you want it hidden in a way which it doesn't affect the layout use `display:none` and finally, if you don't want it rendered at all set `Visible=false` attribute on the `TextBox`.

Comment: You have hit exactly what I am trying to do. I was just wondering if a delay or order of execution could be used to force templatefield to render first.

Comment: _"If you simply want it hidden then you can set Visible=false"_ Not exactly. If you want to hide it completely use CSS `display: none`, then it takes no space. If you want to preserve it's space use `visibility: hidden` If you don't want it to be rendered at all use `Visible=false`. Then the html will not be rendered and the control does not exist on clientside.

Comment: Yes css display none will resolve the issue but I do not want user to be able to access the information by manipulating the css post render.

Comment: Thanks James I have used css. The sensitive data is bound to the textbox and not the empty column so I guess I already had the answer to start with.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yeah that was a typo, what I really meant was "not rendered". I have updated for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to show the column but only textboxes of the selected row?

I would use `RowDataBound` for this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox) e.Row.FindControl("txt");
        txt.Visible = e.Row == ((GridView)sender).SelectedRow;
    }
}
```

or via index:

```
txt.Visible = e.Row.RowIndex == ((GridView)sender).SelectedIndex;
```

But of course the whole column needs to be visible since this property is inherited from it's containers. That means, a child control is visible only if it's visible **and** none of it's parent controls are invisible.

```
<asp:TemplateField Visible="true">
```

Comment: Sorry Tim I guess I wasnt clear enough I have added vb to clarify my question.

Comment: @Obsidion: It's still not clear what "Show textbox that match prerequisite" actually means. However, you should use `RowDataBound` anyway. You can access the datasource of every row via `e.Row.DataItem`. Then add your logic there.

Comment: Because its not relevant to what I am trying to ask. I already have code to show/hide template field and to show desired textboxs. My question is: when a container is set to visible true its contents do not render if also set to visible true at the same time. @James answer has got the right idea.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts.